Electron MariaDB SQL connection failed
I'm trying to create a login system on Electron,and I tried to connect to the database and it keeps showing an error:
SqlError: (conn:-1, no: 45028, SQLState: HY000) retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10001ms
    (pool connections: active=0 idle=0 limit=10)
    at module.exports.createError (VM138 Z:\Electron\node_modules\mariadb\lib\misc\errors.js:66:10)
    at Pool._requestTimeoutHandler (VM210 Z:\Electron\node_modules\mariadb\lib\pool.js:354:26)

My code:
const json = JSON.stringify(env);
    const dbdata = JSON.parse(json);

    document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        const username = document.getElementById('usr').value;
        const password = document.getElementById('pwd').value;

        let hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
        hash.update(password);
        
        let pool = mariadb.createPool({
            host: dbdata.DB_HOST,
            user: dbdata.DB_USER,
            password: dbdata.DB_PASSWORD,
            timeout: 5
        });
        
        pool.getConnection()
            .then(conn => {
                return conn.query('SELECT * FROM accountData WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?', [username, hash.digest('hex')]);
            })
            .then(rows => {
                if(rows.length > 0){
                    alert("ok");
                }
                else{
                    alert("bad");
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    })

My database is on ubuntu on the same internet as my windows pc, I've tried ubuntu's Ip and localhost, but it doesn't work for me.
My Login data is stored in .env file, and I've checked it, it can read it in nNode.js, so the problem may be in the database.
By the way, I've tried the username and password on phpMyAdmin and MariaDB on Ubuntu, both work but not on electron.

Have you tried connecting using another database application on your Windows system?  MySQL has to be configured to allow access from other machines.  phpMyAdmin is not a good test, because that creates the connection on the server, not on your computer.

I finally found an answer, I changed bind-address in /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf, can it successfully connected.
